# Initiate a Twilio call to a number, if call is answered by human, then connect to a second number

Tags: twilio

We would like code that initiates an outbound Twilio call to a callee number.
If Twilio's answering machine detection detects a human has received the call, then we would like the code to immediately connect the caller, ideally with very little delay so that the callee doesn't realize that this happened.
The goal is for people to be able to maximize the number of people that they can try to contact, knowing that only a percentage of calls are answered by humans.  Also, it would be ideal to do this using a TwimL bin, or otherwise fully within Twilio, rather than having to host the code ourselves.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It's better if on answer you ask the human to press a key if they want the call, then connect. More here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/tracking-call-status-how-can-you-tell-if-a-human-answers-the-phone-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Alex's article was the suggested way until the recent public beta launch of [enhanced answering machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/introducing-new-answering-machine-detection.html).

The `MachineDetection` parameter can be set to `Enable` or `DetectMessageEnd`. `Enable` returns results as soon as recognition is complete. `DetectMessageEnd` will wait until after a greeting to return results if an answering machine is detected.

Use AMD via the REST API as seen [in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection):

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789/Calls.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+1562300000' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+18180000000' \
--data-urlencode 'MachineDetection=Enable' \
--data-urlencode 'Url=https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8ccdbd7f0b8fe34357da8ce87ebe5a16' \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789:[AuthToken]
```